# Reading viewlayers from Blender blendfile

Tags: python

I need to get **scenes** and its **viewlayers** in a blendfile using **blendfile.py**.

Currently I can get scenes names and Viewlayers names, but i can not get what scene has what viewlayers...

Getting scenes:

```
# Read blendfile
bf = blendfile.open_blend(path)
scenes = bf.find_blocks_from_code(b'SC')
scene_names = [scene[b'id', b'name'].decode()[2:] for scene in scenes]
```

Getting viewlayers:

```
# Read blendfile
bf = blendfile.open_blend(path)
layers_in_blendfile = [struct for struct in bf.blocks if struct.dna_type_name == 'ViewLayer']
layers_names = [layer[b'name'].decode() for layer in layers_in_blendfile]
```

Any way to get the viewlayers from these scenes or the scene from these viewlayers?

Also, when I try to do `scene[b'view_layers']` i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\software\script\utils\blendfile.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    return self.get(item, use_str=False)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\software\script\utils\blendfile.py", line 450, in get
    return dna_struct.field_get(
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\software\script\utils\blendfile.py", line 834, in field_get
    raise NotImplementedError("%r exists but isn't pointer, can't resolve field %r" %
NotImplementedError: ("b'view_layers' exists but isn't pointer, can't resolve field b'view_layers'", DNAName(b'view_layers'), DNAStruct(b'ListBase'))
```

And if i try to get something random like `scene[b'aa']`, i get a list of possible options:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\software\script\utils\blendfile.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    return self.get(item, use_str=False)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\software\script\utils\blendfile.py", line 450, in get
    return dna_struct.field_get(
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\software\script\utils\blendfile.py", line 794, in field_get
    raise KeyError("%r not found in %r (%r)" %
KeyError: "b'aa' not found in [b'id', b'adt', b'drawdata', b'camera', b'world', b'set', b'base', b'basact', b'_pad1', b'cursor', b'lay', b'layact', b'_pad2', b'flag', b'use_nodes', b'_pad3', b'nodetree', b'ed', b'toolsettings', b'_pad4', b'safe_areas', b'r', b'audio', b'markers', b'transform_spaces', b'orientation_slots', b'sound_scene', b'playback_handle', b'sound_scrub_handle', b'speaker_handles', b'fps_info', b'depsgraph_hash', b'_pad7', b'active_keyingset', b'keyingsets', b'unit', b'gpd', b'clip', b'physics_settings', b'_pad8', b'customdata_mask', b'customdata_mask_modal', b'view_settings', b'display_settings', b'sequencer_colorspace_settings', b'rigidbody_world', b'preview', b'view_layers', b'master_collection', b'collection', b'layer_properties', b'_pad9', b'display', b'eevee', b'grease_pencil_settings'] (b'Scene')"
```